# Python SWIG arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, types, swig

I am wrapping a C module with SWIG for Python. Is there any way to turn all Python lists/tuples whose members are all of the same type (same kind of Swig object) to C arrays?

Answer (score 2):

Typemaps.  What you are most likely looking for is an "in" typemap, which maps Python types to C types.  The declaration looks something like this:

%typemap(in)  {
    /* C code to convert Python tuple object to C array */
}

Inside the typemap code you can use the variable $input to reference the PyObject* to convert, and assign your converted C array to $1.

http://docs.python.org/c-api/ has information on the Python/C API, which you'll need to unpack the tuple to get the items and convert them to C.

http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Typemaps.html has the SWIG documentation for typemaps.

The documentation can be hard to understand at first, so take a look at some example typemaps in /share.  carrays.i in that directory might also serve as a good starting point.